# Не проигрывается анимация при ударе в godot engine

Tags: анимация, godot

**Код области получения урона(hurtbox)**

```
extends Area2D

const HitEffect =  preload("res://Effects/HitEffect.tscn")

func _on_Hurtbox_area_entered(area):
    var effect = HitEffect.instance()
    var main = get_tree().current_scene
    main.add_child(effect)
    effect.global_position = global_position
```

**Код самого AnimatedSprite**

```
extends AnimatedSprite

func _ready():
    connect("animation_finished", self,'_on_animation_finished' )
    frame = 0
    play('Animate')




func _on_animation_finished():
    queue_free()
```

До этого пользовался такими же скриптами для анимации смерти и уничтожения травы, сейчас почему-то работать отказывается, не понимаю почему. Сделано на основе [гайда от Heartbeast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R0XvL3_t840&list=PL9FzW-m48fn2SlrW0KoLT4n5egNdX-W9a&index=16)

Answer (score 0):

последняя строка первого куска кода, вероятно, является причиной. начнем с effects. нигде не вижу переменную с таким именем, откладчик не кусается? второе, само значение переменной. не уверен, но может, надо со ссылкой на сам узел? типа:

```
self.global_position
```